# Are Optimal Tours Sensitive to Clusters?

Tags: discrete-geometry, combinatorial-optimization, data-analysis

Background of this question is that I had been asked for advice in clustering a very big set ($10^6$ to $10^8$) set of points in Euclidean 3D-space; these points in turn lie on 2D manifolds.

I remembered, that the combination of point clusters and optimal tours is beneficially been utilized in [TSP Art](http://www2.oberlin.edu/math/faculty/bosch/making-tspart-page.html) and I wonder, whether my intuition is right, that optimal tours only rarely reenter the same cluster.

If that were actually the case, then a high-dimensional clustering problem could be reduced to identifying associated intervals on the optimal tour, turning the problem into a 1-dimensional one.

> **Question:**
>
> what is known about the usability of optimal tours in clustering problems?

Comment: More common than using "optimal tours", but in similar vein, is the idea of using random walks for clustering. http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~harel/papers/Clustering_FSTTCS.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be trying to solve an easier problem by using a harder problem.
More common is to use clustering to speed TSP construction.
Nevertheless, here is one paper that uses TSP to cluster:

> Climer, Sharlee, and Weixiong Zhang. "Take a walk and cluster genes: A TSP-based approach to optimal rearrangement clustering." *Proceedings of the 21st International Conference on Machine Learning*. ACM, 2004. 
>   [PDF download](http://www1.cse.wustl.edu/~zhang/publications/tsp-icml04.pdf).
>
> ---
>
> [image: Cluster]

---

Comment: The interesting thing about clusters and TSP seems to be that having information about one of them simplifies the task of determining the other,